# IRestResponse return content mvc c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have built an API which posts parameter to external an URL and got works perfect how can I return the content I am using asp.net MVC core c#

This is my trial

```
 [HttpPost("post")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> postuser(postDtos postdDtos)
        {

            var client = new RestClient("https://www.xxxx.com/post");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"UserName\": \"" +  postdDtos.UserName + "\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            return StatusCode(response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK ? 400 : 201);

        }
```

I need to change status code 400: 201 to response content How can I achieve it especially I used IActionResult and when I change it to IRestResponse the API doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, check out the response and make your response DTO class.
2. After that deserialize the response using NewtonSoft or some other library, and return as JSON.

   ```
       [HttpPost("post")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> postuser(postDtos postdDtos)
       {

           var client = new RestClient("https://www.xxxx.com/post");
           var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
           request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
           request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
           request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"UserName\": \"" +  postdDtos.UserName + "\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
           IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
           var status = StatusCode(response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK ? 400 : 201);
           var yourDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourDTO>(response.Content);
           return Json(new {status = status , response = "Blech"});
       }
   ```